# Can't request Eventhub Dedicated Sku

Tags: terraform, azure-eventhub

I have a simple module for an eventhub configuration.

```
resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "my-namespace" {
  name                = var.velocity_eventhub_namespace_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg_name
  sku                 = var.eventhub-sku
  capacity            = var.capacity
}
```

If `var.eventhub-sku` is set to "Dedicated" so that I may provision more than 10 Eventhubs in the namespace, I get

`Error: expected sku to be one of [Basic Standard], got Dedicated`

Is there anyway around this? Do I have to do some part of the configuration manually?
Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

'Dedicated' is not a valid SKU for EH namespaces. Allowed namespace SKUs are Basic, and Standard. Dedicated is a cluster offering from Event Hubs. Please see more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dedicated-overview